# Adding scroll bar to dynamic ul li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I searched through many posts and forum as i thought this might be a basic stuff but didnot find it so asking here,All i am trying to do is add scroll bar if the height is more than certain limit lets say if menu items are more than 3.

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/euSWB/

If you are not able to access it then here is the HTML and CSS
HTML

```
<ul id="mnav">

<li><a><b>Home</b></a>
</li>
<li><a><b>SQL Server vs Oracle</b></a>
 <ul>

<li><a>Basic SQL : Declare variables and assign values</a></li>

<li><a>Basic SQL : Inner Join, Outer Join and Cross Join</a></li>

<li><a>Basic SQL : Padding and Trimming</a></li>

<li><a>Basic SQL : Union,Except/Minus,Intersect</a></li>

<li><a style="border-bottom-color: currentColor; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-bottom-style: none;">Update from Select</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#"><b>SSIS</b></a>
 <ul>
<li><a>Coalesce in SSIS</a></li>
<li><a >Universal CSV Generator</a></li>
<li><a >Parsing a row into multiple in CSV</a></li>


<li><a style="border-bottom-color: currentColor; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-bottom-style: none;" >XML Task in SSIS</a></li>
</ul>
 </li></ul>
```

CSS

```
#mnav {
margin-left: -30px;
margin-right: -30px;
}
#mnav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
}
#mnav li a, #mnav li a:link, #mnav li a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}
#mnav li a:hover, #mnav li a:active {
text-decoration: none;
}
#mnav li:hover, #mnav li.sfhover {
position: static;
}
#mnav li ul {
display: block;
z-index: 9999;
position: absolute;
left: -999em;
width: 400px;
margin: 0px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#mnav li:hover ul, #mnav li.sfhover ul {
left: auto;
}
#mnav li ul li a, #mnav li ul li a:link, #mnav li ul li a:visited {
display: block;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 9999;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
width: 500px;
}
#mnav li ul li a:hover, #mnav li ul li a:active {
display: block;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've made a couple of adjustments to your original stylesheet, and now it will show the scroll bar, but only when it exceeds the height of 3 list items (63 pixels in this case). Here's the final CSS code:

```
#mnav {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
}
#mnav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 10px;/*Keeping 10px space between each nav element*/
}
#mnav li a,/*These can all be merged into a single style*/
#mnav li a:link,
#mnav li a:visited,
#mnav li a:hover,
#mnav li a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mnav li ul {
    display: none;/*This is the default state.*/
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    max-height:63px;/*The important part*/
    overflow-y:auto;/*Also...*/
    overflow-x:hidden;/*And the end of the important part*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left:5px;/*Removing the large whitespace to the left of list items*/
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#mnav li:hover ul, #mnav li.sfhover ul {
    display:block;/*This is the hovered state*/
}
#mnav li ul li a, #mnav li ul li a:link, #mnav li ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    width:400px;
}
#mnav li ul li a:hover, #mnav li ul li a:active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**[Here's the demo of it](http://jsfiddle.net/euSWB/18/)**. I've also, for demonstration purposes, inserted 2 extra `<li>` elements to the **Home** and **SQL Server vs Oracle** items. The **Home** item will show how the popup behaves if there are fewer than 3 list items there.

To explain each of the changed bits, first the code that actually does the trick:

- defining the `max-height` to 63 will make the ul behave normally if it stays under 63px high, but if it exceeds that, it will overflow and show a scroll bar. If you want to show more items, just increase the `max-height` to the desired height. Currently the height of each item is 21px, so I used that to get the 63px for 3 items.
- Since the overflow should only show a scroll bar for the vertical direction, only `overflow-y:auto;` should be there, and `overflow-x:hidden` to prevent a scrollbar in the horizontal direction.

And then the other general changes I made:

- I've added 20px margin between items (10px on either side of the element) to make the list look a bit better here. You may want to apply your own style though, this is just for this demo.
- I've changed your hiding technique from 'shoving it off to `-999em` to the left' to hiding it via `display:none`. This is better to work with, since elements that are `display:none` will not render in search engines, so this will help in those situations. In general I think hiding things with `display:none` is just better than shoving it off the screen, while it's still actually there
- I've removed the padding to the left of the `ul` since it just looked quite bad. No need for the default padding if you're not using it for a dotted/numbered list.

This should also work considering your comment to *Zachary Carter*'s answer, since this won't show a huge white box if you define the `max-height` to 210px (10 items).

Comment: when i posted this question I was wondering there must be something like max height,that is what i was exactly searching, i am sure this answer will help a lot of people like me Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have predictable list item heights, this is fairly trivial. Consider the following example:

```html
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>This is option one.</li>
    <li>This is a second option.</li>
    <li>We'll need three.</li>
    <li>And now these are out of view.</li>
    <li>I'm the last option.</li>
</ul>
```

Here we have this list of five items. I will instruct each of the list items themselves to have a `font-size` and `line-height` of `1em`, with a padding of `.25em` on the top and bottom:

```css
.sub-menu li {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .25em 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

So now we know that each list item is `1.5em` tall. As such, we can now set the `max-height` on our parent element so that it only shows three list items at a time:

```css
.sub-menu {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 4.5em; /* 1.5 x 3 */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The results:

[image]

Online Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/euSWB/16/

Comment: As you can see from my fiddle I have multiple menu items and sub categories, could you please implement the above for multiple levels of ul li

Comment: @sam When you say "multiple levels," are you talking about sub menus within sub menus? I don't see that in your example.

Comment: I was talking about multiple main menus with submenus, but submenu to open only when we hover main menu, this is how I tried to implement your code in mine http://jsfiddle.net/euSWB/17/ but It is giving an extra horizontal scroll bar so wanted you to help me in implement your code for my li ul's

Comment: @sam I see an extra scroll bar on the viewport; that is what you're talking about, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, please rewrite the CSS if you there is another way, FYI If i remove width: 500px; from "#mnav li ul li a, #mnav li ul li a:link, #mnav li ul li" the veritcal scroll bar is going away but SSIS tab(third tab) is having submenu items next to each other instead of stack

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things...

First of all you're not specifying a height for your unordered list. You'll never see a scrollbar if you don't define a height for the element. The element will adjust its size to its contents.

Also, if you want to prevent the contents of the UL from overflowing the element horizontally, set the overflow-x CSS3 property to hidden.

I think what you need is something like :

```
#mnav li ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/euSWB/9/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just took 3 as an example but i really wanted 10 items and then scroll , I tried to implement height but it didnot work because if there are few items in a tab then it is creating a big blank box for that tab and it doesnt look pretty

Comment: I'm not sure why you're downvoting my answer because it doesn't look pretty. You didn't ask in your question for how to make it look pretty. You asked how to get your element to display a scroll bar and I answered you with a completely viable solution. If you want it to look pretty, then explain that in your question in the future.

Comment: FYI someone else downgraded your answer