# Limit number of items in dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

Here's the code:

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"></label>

        <div class="checker">
            <label class="checkbox"><span><input name="multiselect" type=
            "checkbox" value="1"></span></label>
        </div>Menu Item</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"></label>

        <div class="checker">
            <label class="checkbox"><span><input name="multiselect" type=
            "checkbox" value="57"></span></label>
        </div>Menu Item</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"></label>

        <div class="checker">
            <label class="checkbox"><span><input name="multiselect" type=
            "checkbox" value="59"></span></label>
        </div>Menu Item</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"></label>

        <div class="checker">
            <label class="checkbox"><span><input name="multiselect" type=
            "checkbox" value="60"></span></label>
        </div>Menu Item</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"></label>

        <div class="checker">
            <label class="checkbox"><span><input name="multiselect" type=
            "checkbox" value="14"></span></label>
        </div>Menu Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is limit the amount of items in a dropdown menu.  For example, I only want 10 items to show when a user clicks it, then they can scroll down to view the rest.

The problem I'm having right now is that users with a large amount of items in the dropdown menu are currently having it extend past the end of the page...

Comment: Have any CSS to share? Essentially you need `max-height:40px; overflow:auto;`. If you apply this on the `ul` directly, it will scroll but not show a scrollbar. I'd recommend putting it on a container `div`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding scroll bar to dynamic ul li](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746745/adding-scroll-bar-to-dynamic-ul-li)

Comment: I think this is an IA issue, since more than around [7-8 items in a dropdown menu](http://www.mcgill.ca/web-101/architecture) is cognitive clutter for the user. If you work out menu labels with a [card sort](http://boxesandarrows.com/card-sorting-a-definitive-guide/) it will help split long menu items into logical groups and make it easier for users navigate more effectively.